# How to get the end date of an event using eventClick Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

How can i get the event end date using eventClick, we already tried to use view.end but it gives different date and the event.end doesn't exist.

we are planning to edit the event using a modal and populate the input box when eventclick.

Thank you

sample code

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
    console.log(moment(event.end).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
}
```

the event is working when you view it on the calendar, the start and end date is set.

Comment: Please provide code that demonstrates your problem. `event.end` should work fine.

Comment: console.log(event.end) gives us undefined value.

Comment: Please provide more code that indicates what `event` is in that context and possibly some test events. Since the `end` parameter is optional, perhaps your event doesn't have an end date -- so it would be expected that `event.end` doesn't exist. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3vm501ea/1/)

Comment: the start and end date were set using php code. when we try to console.log() the event, the "end" is missing.

Comment: Please provide a [minimum, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem. My example post above works as expected: on click, it shows the `end` date when the `end` parameter exists, and it doesn't work when `end` parameter doesn't exist.

Comment: do i need to enable something in order to show end date in the function(event, jsEvent, view) ?